# Saving Listview item permanently in the android application

Tags: android

I have created an android application in which the value i give in edittext will be displayed on listview,  but when i click back to another activity and return back to the listview activity the listview items will be disappeared.  Please tell me how to save listview items permanently in the activity.

Below is my code.

```
   public class Edit extends Activity {
```

ArrayList listitems=new ArrayList();
ArrayAdapter adapter;

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listitems);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listitems.add(et.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Are you populating your listview on onCreate?

Answer (score 1):

When you say back, I assume that your are saying that you click the back button. Clicking the back button would destroy the current activity, so all non-persistent changes will be lost and just adding items to an adapter is a non-persistent change.

Therefore, you will have to save these add events persistently somehow. In android, there are a few ways to save thing persistently. If you want to save alot of events, I would recommend going with a local [sqllite db](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)  or if you don't need to worry about saving alot of these events, I would go with [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Therefore, you could do something like this in your code if you decided to go with Shared Preferences:

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listitems.add(et.getText().toString());

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       saveStringToPreferences(et.getText());

}

private void saveStringToPreferences(String str){
     SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
     editor.putString("label", str);
     editor.apply();
}
```

now to load the items back in your list, when you come back to the activity:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String previousText = preferences.getString("label", "");
    if(! TextUtils.isEmpty(previousText)){
        listitems.add(et.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes clicking on back button only.How to use Shared Preferences for listview items,please give me some references or tell me how to save listview items using shared preferences.Thank you.

Comment: @SowmyashreeVasu sure, you can't actually save the state of the adapter (or the listvew) persistently so your goal will be to save a representation of whatever happens to your list view in shared preferences. For example, you could save whatever text you obtain from the edittext in a shared preference. Then when you come back to this activity, check your shared preferences for any existing strings, if the shared preferences does contain any string, (that means we must have saved from when the user pressed the button before) so we just add the string to the list now.

Comment: I give the value in edittext and click on add button that will be saved in as listview item.I want listview items to be saved permanently,so that if i return back to the listview activity those listview items should be present.

Comment: Ok,I added a code example that should work, try this out and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Andre Perkins,I will try this out.

Comment: Getting error as--> the method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){})

Comment: ,sorry i added that method inside onview.

Comment: oh ok. no worries. :)

Comment: that code didn't work for...it is not saving the listview items

Comment: I am not getting any error,but when I return back to listview activity I have lost the data in listview,listview items which I have added is not being saved.